# How to interpret op amp minimum supply voltage if the datasheet field is blank?

Tags: operational-amplifier, datasheet

I'm trying to find the minimum supply voltage for the LF356N op amp. In the "LF35x" line from the datasheet below, that field is left blank. Same goes for the *Absolute Max Ratings* (not shown here).

I'm looking for an op amp that will continue to function even as batteries wear down, which is why I want to know the minimum supply voltage at which the op amp will still function.

How should I interpret the datasheet?

EDIT: Datasheet link [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf356.pdf)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Add a link into your question so we're all singing from the same datasheet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The datasheet seems to have lost some coherence in the translation from NS to TI. If you look at an [original datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LF356N/NOPB-National-Semiconductor-datasheet-7085376.pdf), it's clear that the recommended voltage is 15V for the LM356N and the maximum is +/-18V.

It's not clear what the recommended minimum is, however it's specified at +/-15V. Curves of **typical** performance go down to +/-5V so probably you're okay down to 10V (obviously with reduced output swing and input range).

Comment: The web site also says +/-5 as minimum http://www.ti.com/product/LF356/description#parametrics

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned, it looks like the data sheet lacks a bit.

If nothing else, look at the output voltage swing.  It's listed as \$\pm\$10V for a 2k\$\Omega\$ load and \$\pm\$15V supply.  That means that the output is dropping **5V** in each direction -- so if you give it a 2k\$\Omega\$ load and a \$\pm\$5V supply it'll have barely any output swing at all.